# XML XSL xsl:sort Is not sorting the file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to sort this simple table by date or location but nothing seems to be working. It seems that is not applying sorting at all. I have search for some tips on the websites like w3c and forums but i cant make it work.

here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="travelDiaries.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<diaries>
    <diary name='Wojciech'>
          <entry date='2020/06/12' title='Poland'>
            <location>Poland</location>
            <description>Trip to see the, family and friends in a home town</description>
            <img></img>
         </entry>
    </diary>

    <diary name='Karolina'>
        <entry date='2018/04/12' title='Poland'>
            <location>Poland</location>
            <description>Trip for site visiting, visiting a Capital city of Poland - Warsaw </description>
            <img></img>
        </entry>
    </diary>

     <diary name='Kuba'>
          <entry date='2019/03/02' title='Czech republic'>
            <location>Czech republic</location>
            <description>Visiting the Old Praque with friends, seeing most popular sites</description>
            <img></img>
         </entry>
    </diary>

     <diary name='Kevin'>
          <entry date='2020/11/08' title='Usa'>
            <location>Usa</location>
            <description>Traveling around different states, meeting people and learning about the culture</description>
            <img></img>
         </entry>
    </diary>
</diaries>
```

and here is XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/diaries">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="5">
                    <tr bgcolor="lawngreen">
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                    </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="diary">
                    <xsl:for-each select="entry">
                          <xsl:sort select="entry/@date"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@date"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="location"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img border="1" width="100px" height="100px">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                <xsl:value-of select="img"/>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                </img>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I really feel stuck with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="diary">
    <xsl:for-each select="entry">
        <xsl:sort select="entry/@date"/>
```

This attempts to sort the `entry`s of each `diary` - but each `diary` has only one `entry`. In addition, you are already in the context of `entry`, and from this context the expression `entry/@date` selects nothing, because `entry` is not a child of itself.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:for-each select="diary/entry">
    <xsl:sort select="@date"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using one `xsl:for-each` too much.
Just reduce your XSLT-1.0 code to...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/diaries">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="5">
                    <tr bgcolor="lawngreen">
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="diary">
                        <xsl:sort select="entry/@date"/>
                        <xsl:sort select="entry/location"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="entry/@date"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="entry/location"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="entry/description"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img border="1" width="100px" height="100px">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="entry/img"/>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                </img>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...and your output will be sorted by `@date` and `location`.

Comment: I have tried this solution, but it doesn't work. The content of the table is not displayed. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score -1):

@Cahirsu - You can try at this way for multiple sorting:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="pr">
        **<xsl:perform-sort select="entry">
            <xsl:sort select="@date" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="location" order="ascending"/>                
        </xsl:perform-sort>**
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

And apply variable $pr